# Getting Polars for Rust with Arrow support working on Windows

Tags: rust, rust-polars

This appears to be the pertinent documentation [polars::prelude::IpcWriter](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/struct.IpcWriter.html) which says "Available on crate feature polars-io only". However, if I add `polars = { version = "0.36.2", features = ["polars-io"] }` to my Cargo.toml, it still isn't found. I looked through the polars code and it appears that the ipc feature might be required so I add that. Then I get an error that it failed the custom build for `zstd-sys v2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5`. I think that's a compression library which I shouldn't need for what I'm doing, so I try to figure out how to remove it from the build. But between disabling default features and adding things back in, I haven't found a combination that will build (ie. exclude zstd) and give me the Arrow support I need.

Is there a way to exclude zstd from the build? Or if easier, get the zstd build to succeed.

Comment: The correct way is to resolve the build error for `zstd`, probably. However, `zstd` comes from `polars-arrow` which comes from `polars-io` if the `ipc` feature is enabled.

Comment: You didn't give us enough info about the build error, so we cannot resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears there is no way to disable the `zstd` dependency. The `IpcWriter` is only compiled under the `ipc` or `ipc_streaming` features of `polars-io`, both of which activate `polars-arrow/io_ipc_compression`, and that activates the `zstd` dependency.